# Bootstrap class="h-100" working in firefox but not chrome

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, flexbox

I'm using Bootstrap and leaflet to build a web map and would like the map to cover the entire height of the main container on the page. What I have so far is working in Firefox but not in Chrome or Safari.

I have a `<body>` with `min-height: 100vh` and inside that a `<main>` tag with `flex: 1 0 auto` so that the `<main>` element always fills the space between the `<nav>` and `<footer>`.

Within `<main>` I have `<div class="container-fluid h-100">` which I expect to have the height of `<main>`, and within the container I have `<div id="map" class="h-100">` which I expect to have the height of the container.

This works as expected in Firefox:
[container with height containing map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PL5NJ.png), but not in Chrome or Safari: [container with height 0 and no visible map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PtOiK.png).

I've seen that most issues related to % based heights are due to parent elements having no height, but that's not the case here as even in Chrome the `<main>` element has a height: [`<main>` with height](https://i.stack.imgur.com/glcqK.png).

Is this related to the `flex` property set on the `<main>` tag and it's height being evaluated differently in different browsers?

Here's the full HTML skeleton I'm using:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
  </head>

  <body class="bg-dark">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="/"></a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-dark border-0" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#nav-content" aria-controls="nav-content" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation menu">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="nav-content">
        <ul class="navbar-nav align-items-center">
          <li class="nav-item ">
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item ">
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item ">
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <main>
      <div class="container-fluid h-100">
        <div id="map" class="h-100"></div>
      </div>
    </main>

    <footer>
    </footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

And relevant CSS:

```
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

main {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asked before I had messed around enough. Adding the following CSS fixed the issue:

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
```

I don't completely understand why this worked so if anyone has an explanation I'd be happy to accept a more complete answer.